# Docker Performance Testing

Tags: java, performance, docker, jmeter, artifactory

We have an Artifactory endpoint which we want to performance test.

For that we want to inject load of multiple Docker image files to the Artifactory server.

What is the best way to create such multiple image file load?

Ideally we would like to tie this in to JMeter so that JMeter itself can upload Docker image files to Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JFrog to push your docker images.
They provide API using which you can directly send the images to the Artifactory.
Following links may be helpful:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry

Comment: It is exactly this API that I want to test. How performant is it - for that I need to simulate load - which I am not sure what the best way to do is right now.

Comment: You want to test the API performance?
In that case you can use Jmeter, to do load testing, they provide lot of API's to do that.

Comment: Yes thats true - so I am writing a Docker JMeter connector. So this will enable me to execute Docker commands in JMeter itself. The question though is how will the test images be spun so quickly? I need to generate a LOT of load. So for instance I might need to generate 1000 temporary Docker image files - what is the best and quickest way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to test same type of image 1000 times, if image is working fine on one configuration it will work exactly same on similar conf, that's the whole idea of dockerization.

Comment: The idea is to see how the system is being stressed by the load and to see how many concurrent users can do Docker push/pulls and to see what the upper limit of bandwidth is. Basically to determine the performance characterstics of my Docker registry in Artifactory. The only way to do it is to put the system under stress and see how well it does.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can do virtually whatever you want with JMeter scripting components (which basically uses a "loose Java" language called Beanshell).
Or at least whatever has Java implementation.

Though it may be not very efficient in moving really big stuff around. How big your images are, BTW?

So maybe custom test harness would pay off better.

PS Or, perhaps, some plugins could help, like [this one](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/).

Comment: The link did not populate. Grateful if you could post again.

Comment: ooops... sorry, something gone wrong with the link, updated now